# read.csv column of zeros and ones as logical

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

How can a column of ones and zeros be read in directly as `logical`, thereby avoiding subsequent conversions?

In a large csv file, several columns have values of zero or one, which I'd like to use as logical variables in R.

If I specify those `colClasses` as logical, then `read.csv` complains **expected 'a logical', got '0'**:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, 
dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'a logical', got '0'
```

On the other hand, `read.csv` succeeds if I specify those `colClasses` as integer. Afterwards, I am able to convert them using `as.logical()`.

Comment: My guess would be that you can only do this/read them in directly if the values are `TRUE` and `FALSE` (or `T` and `F`).  Why do you want/need to do this?  For efficiency, or clarity, or ... ?

Comment: I certainly agree you shouldn't munge the source file.   I still don't know what's wrong with reading and then converting.   In your place I would write a little wrapper function to read and then convert.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** no, not possible as far as I know.

I don't know why you're unhappy post-converting, but you could write a wrapper: assuming that you never actually want to read in a column that contains `T`/`F`/`TRUE`/`FALSE` values:

```
read.csv2 <- function(file,colClasses,...) {
  lcols <- which(colClasses=="logical")
  colClasses[lcols] <- "integer"
  x <- read.csv(file,colClasses=colClasses,...)
  x[lcols] <- lapply(x[lcols],as.logical)
  x
}
```

(untested!)

Otherwise, I would file a feature request for `readr` or `data.table::fread` or ...

As far as I know, and until someone presents evidence to the contrary, the answer to your original question

> How can a column of zeros and ones be read in directly as logical [using only base R functions such as `read.table`], thereby avoiding subsequent conversions?

"is this impossible?"; not unreasonable, but not possible.  You can file a feature request at http://bugs.r-project.org, or discuss this further on `r-devel@r-project.org` ...

Answer (score 4):

If this is a regular occurrence you can create an `as`-method for a class and then give that class name as a character value to the colClasses parameter. (The `read.*` functions will attempt to apply any as-methods to the values being read in within a column. See `?read.table`. As described there the as-method must convert a "character" value to the desired type.)

```
 setClass("zero.one", contains=logical())
 setAs("character", "zero.one", function(from){ 
                             as.logical(as.numeric(from ) )} )


 input <- read.csv("fil.nam", colClasses = c( ..., "zero.one" ...) )

 txt <- "1,2,3\n0,0,1\nf,0,8\n"
 read.csv(text=txt, colClasses="zero.one")
     X1    X2   X3
1 FALSE FALSE TRUE
2    NA FALSE TRUE
```